I am getting this error on VSCode. "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" Manage and change your permissions to get this to work
I don't know what to do. I don't have administrator permissions at the company I work at. VSCode's advice was to "Ask on Stack Overflow". Can somebody help?
I tried looking through their help page and some of the settings they were referring to weren't available to me and it was overall confusing.
Error Comes when I load up the program and everytime I try to run it.

It would help if you said where this error came from.  What you were trying to do?

I'm guessing it's because VSCode defaults to Powershell for it's terminal environment, so can't open it to run shell commands. You can change this to cmd as your default, which may work without elevated privileges. Below is someone asking how to do that specifically with some clear answers:
Visual Studio Code, how to switch from powershell.exe to cmd.exe
